# Loop through row if value found copy the whole row and paste underneath/bottom row

Tags: vba, excel

I have spent some trying getting my code to work and looking through various example but still cant get it to work properly.

I have a table  where I want to loop through all rows and if "Pro" found in column B , copy the whole row and paste it once either underneath the row or at the very bottom(ideally) (Picture attached before and after the code)

I tried with the below code but all it does is finding the first instance of "Pro" in column B and copying same row until range 50 reaches:

```
sub Loop()
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 50
Range("B" & i).Select
If Range("B" & i).Value = "Pro" Then      
Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy
Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

End If
 Next i
End Sub
```

I tried with (For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row )
as well, defining last column but same thing happens(end up copying same row over and over again until the specified range finish).

If this will be too easy, I want for a copied row to have a value in Column A changed as well from as an exaple Req2 to Req2Pro

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnWNH.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit this line:

```
Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy
Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

With:

```
Rows(i + 50).Value = Rows(i).Value
Range("A" & i + 50).value =  Range("A" & i).value & "Pro"
```

This is it in the code:

```
 Sub testloop()
 Dim i As Long
 Dim Find_last_row as long
 Find_last_row = cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row

 For i = 1 To Find_last_row
    If Range("B" & i).Value = "Pro" Then
       Rows(i + Find_last_row).Value = Rows(i).Value
       Range("A" & i + Find_last_row).value =  Range("A" & i).value & "Pro"
    End If
 Next i
 End Sub
```

Comment: This will paste them 25 rows after its found but still repeatedly copies the same row over and over if its pasted within the range. Would be ideal to paste only once and continue looping through text.

Comment: It will but what if i dont know number of rows, can i make 50 as a variable last row (i.e (For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row )

Answer (score 1):

Run the for-next loop descending, e.g,

```
for row = 50 to 1 step -1
    ...
   .cells(row+1,1)=.cells(row,1) & "Pro"
next
```

The issue is that it finds a "Pro" and inserts a copy one row down, then advances the row counter and finds the copy. By running from the bottom up instead, the rows created have already been passed

edited to add column A update

```
Sub Loop()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 50 To 1 step -1
        Range("B" & i).Select
        If Range("B" & i).Value = "Pro" Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy
            Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Range("A" & i + 1).Value = Range("A" & i).Value & "Pro"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Edited to add the above

Comment: I cant seem to make it work 
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 50
Range("B" & i).Select
If Range("B" & i).Value = "Pro" Then
For Row = 50 To 1 Step -1
    ...
   .Cells(Row + 1, 1) = .Cells(Row, 1) & "Pro"
Next

End If
 Next i
End Sub

Comment: You're still using i = 1 to 50. The suggestion was to replace "i = 1 to 50" with "i = 50 to 1 step -1". I will update my answer to make it clearer.